# jQuery function to sometimes redirect after an AJAX Request is completed and to sometimes remain on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page that lets you Add/Edit/Delete "Project Tasks" and Save the data to a database using jQuery's AJAX function to save the POST data.

I currently have 2 buttons on the page.

**Button 1** `.save-tasks-ajax-redirect` - You click it and it makes a regular non-ajax POST to my backend and you are redirected to another Project page.  This button does not have a click event yet.  Perhaps the best way might be to simply create a new click event for this button class and then have it call my save function but it could pass in a variable to indicate that it needs to redirect?  Before I posted this questions I was sort of hoping to have both button share the same click event and everything but perhaps this is a better idea?

**Button 2** `.save-tasks-ajax` - You click it and it uses AJAX to Save the data and you can remain on the page editing more.

Now my goal is to modify how **Button 1** works.  Instead of making a regular HTTP POST, I would like for it to also make an AJAX save but when it is done, I would like it to redirect to a project page.

So below I have my 2 button HTML codes.  Below that I have my jQuery Click event for my AJAX save button (Button 2) and below that I have my `ajaxSaveTasks()` function that my button calls to make the save.

I would like to modify this function and perhaps all of this code so that my `Button 1` can use the same function to make an AJAX save but somehow it needs to differentiate itself so that it can also do a redirect after the AJAX save is complete.

Looking at the basic code below, how could I modify this to do that?

```
<button type="submit" class="save-tasks-ajax-redirect">Save Tasks and Return to Project</button>

<button type="submit" class="save-tasks-ajax">Save Tasks and Continue Editing</button>



$(window).load(function () {

    // AJAX Save and Continue editing
    $('#content').on('click', '.save-tasks-ajax', function () {
        console.log('AJAX Save and Continue Editing Button Clicked!');
        ajaxSaveTasks();
        return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    });

});



function ajaxSaveTasks(){
    console.log('ajaxSaveChanges() Ran and Tasks Saved.');

    // Reset Flag that Triggers Un-Saved Alert on page exit
    window.unsavedChanges = false;

    // Show a Loading/Saving Spinner
    jQuery('#project_tasks').showLoading();

    // Display a message to the user that we are Saving
    flipNotify.show({
        message: 'Project Tasks Saved!',
        icon: 'tick',
        delay: 2,
        sticky: false
    });

    var url = "index.php?module=apoll_Web_Projects";

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#editTasksForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               // Hide Header Un-Saved Changes Div
               hideTaskUnSavedChangesHeaderBar()

               // Hide Loading/Saving Spinner
               jQuery('#project_tasks').hideLoading();
           }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(window).load(function () {

    // AJAX Save and Continue editing
    $('#content').on('click', '.save-tasks-ajax', function () {
        console.log('AJAX Save and Continue Editing Button Clicked!');
        ajaxSaveTasks();
        return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    });

    // AJAX Save and redirect
    $('#content').on('click', '.save-tasks-ajax-redirect', function () {
        console.log('AJAX Save and Redirect Button Clicked!');
        ajaxSaveTasks(function(){ window.location.assign("project.php"); });
        return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    });
});

function ajaxSaveTasks(callback){
    ... your code ...

    $.ajax({
           ...
           success: function(data)
           {
               // Hide Header Un-Saved Changes Div
               hideTaskUnSavedChangesHeaderBar()

               // Hide Loading/Saving Spinner
               jQuery('#project_tasks').hideLoading();

               if (callback)
                 callback();
           }
    });
};
```

Comment: Perfect, I had just updated my question with an idea similar to this, passing in a variable to flag a redirect or not so it looks like this might be on the right track =) I like the idea of a callback function even better too